# On the Bitcoin wallet app for Android

Tags: wallet, address, android

I can't switch between addresses so any coin I have in other wallets isn't accessible. Does anyone know how to solve this? It's the app with the bitcoin symbol on a yellow circle background for Android. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Opendoorexe, could you please clarify the name of the software you're using? You appear to be trying to use the same wallet from multiple devices, how did you attempt to synchronize the wallet across the devices?

Comment: Are you using https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet&gl=GB "Bitcoin Wallet for Android" by "Bitcoin Wallet Developers"  also sometimes known as the Schildbach wallet to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: It's one device but multiple wallets. It's called Bitcoin Wallet and it is created by Bitcoin Wallet Developers as said by RedGrittyBrick. There are many addresses there only 2 of them have coin but I can only send from one wallet and I'm not sure how to change the primary wallet to get access to my coin.